# Moment Generating Function of conditional R.V.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, moment-generating-functions

Suppose Y is a R.V. which is equal to following other R.V. depending on parameter *i*, i.e.

\begin{equation}
Y=\begin{Bmatrix}
 X_1 & i=1 \\ 
 X_2 & i=2 \\ 
 X_3 & i=3
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}

where MGF of $X_i$ is given as,$$M_{X_i}(t) = \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^{i} (e^t + e^{2t} + e^{3t})^i e^{it}$$
How can one find the MGF of Y, given that R.V., **i** is equally likely?

Comment: Law of Total Expectation / Probability?

Comment: How is $Y$ dependent on $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the law of total expectation

$$
M_{Y}(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{Yt}\right] = \sum_{j=1}^{3}\mathbb{E}\left[\left.e^{Yt}\right|i=j\right]P\left(i=j\right)$$

If each one of them is equally likely then

$$
M_{Y}(t) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{3}M_{X_{i}}(t) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{i}\left(e^{t}+e^{2t}+e^{3t}\right)^{i}e^{it} = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\sum_{i=1}^{3}Z^{i}=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)Z\frac{1-Z^{3}}{1-Z}$$
where $Z\equiv\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(e^{t}+e^{2t}+e^{3t}\right)e^{t}$